# set the image's origin with css on hover

Tags: css, image

i want to enlarge an image on hover with css. but when it grows, it grows from the top-left. how can i make it grow from the center?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something obvious, I think you'll have to manually offset the `img` on `:hover`:

See: http://jsfiddle.net/QwvRk/

```
img {
    position: relative
}
img:hover {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    top: -25px;
    left: -25px
}
```

Comment: wow that looks right! jsfiddle: a great way to win the checkmark :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to animate the size and placement at the same time.  As far as i know, the only way to do that is with an absolutely positioned item.  So if you are using jQuery it would be:

```
$('#selector').animate({
top: -=20px,
height: += 20px,
width: += 20px}, 250);
```